# Using join with Content Provider to query from multiple tables

Tags: android, sqlite, join, android-sqlite, android-contentprovider

I am trying to retrieve data from 7 tables and needs to join them to retrieve data , and I am trying to implement Content Provider for this project. I got lots of sample to follow for a single table execution using content provider, but can't get a strong sample to follow for the join case. And in advance I need to pass a string parameter to query for joining table on the base of that string parameter.

for sample I was trying with two tables with not much of luck to pass parameter

```
     case JOIN_FOR_ALL_EVENT_TABLE:

       //it is used to get Id but I need a string parameter to pass 
       //it here, and I don't know how can I achieve that. 
       //This works for only case of id not the String.    
       // And the event_id in my case is a string needs to have - symbol                      
       //on it.  

     _id = ContentUris.parseId(uri);
            Log.e("************* args ",_id + "");
            retCursor = db.rawQuery(
                    "SELECT * " +
                            "from " +
                            "event_info" + " LEFT JOIN "
                            + "wild_animal_info" + " ON "
                            + "event_info.event_id"
                            + " = " + "wild_animal_info.event_id"+" WHERE "+"event_info.event_id"+" ="+ args[0] ,null);
            break;

        default:
```

And the dbHelper looks like this for join

```
/**
 * Method to get all data using join
 */

public void getAllDataFromEventId(String eventId){

    Cursor cursor = myCR.query(ContentUris.withAppendedId(
            TigerContract.CONTENT_URI_RELATIONSHIP_JOIN, id),null,null,null,null);

    if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
        Log.v("***********","size of crsor "+cursor.getCount());
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        Log.v("********NEW ",cursor.getString(1));
        Log.v("********NEW ",cursor.getString(2));
        Log.v("********NEW ",cursor.getString(4));
        Log.v("********NEW ",cursor.getString(5));

    }else{
        cursor.close();

        Log.v("*********New ","Didn't got anything there");
    }
```

And all other thing I did in contract class for Join are

```
   public static final String PATH_JOIN_FOR_ALL_EVENT_TALBE = "join_for_all_event_table";
   public static final Uri CONTENT_URI_RELATIONSHIP_JOIN= BASE_CONTENT_URI.buildUpon().appendPath(PATH_JOIN_FOR_ALL_EVENT_TALBE).build();
   public static final String CONTENT_TYPE_JOIN = "vnd.android.cursor.item/" + CONTENT_AUTHORITY +"/"+ PATH_JOIN_FOR_ALL_EVENT_TALBE;
```

So, I am waiting for a strong sample to follow on for join case in Content Provider. And thanks in advance for all the good people out there.